# Make a Fetch request with join with Azure Mobile Service in iOS

Tags: ios, azure, core-data, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Azure Mobile Services in my app with offline syncing. I'm syncing multiple tables in my CoreData that have relation ID between them.

I want to know if there a solution to fetch by making a join with multiple tables with Azure Mobile Service on CoreData.

Maybe I missed something, but I don't see how the relations could be made with Azure Mobile service in Core Data

My case is I have an object who can have multiple category. So many of these object can have the same category and have many categories.

Let's say that I have three tables : Category, Category_Object and Object

and I want to get all objects who contain a certain category.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

For now, this is the accepted answer until someone find that one day Mobile Services SDK can create the relationships in Core Data

Comment: Can you give examples of the table structure and joins you need to make?  Couldn't you implement corresponding relationships in the CoreData model, and use the relationID to populate those relationships when you download to CoreData?

Comment: @pbasdf I updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the Azure Mobile Services `Category` and `Object` tables each have a unique id, say `categoryID` and `objectID` respectively, and that the `Category_Object` table also has a unique id, say `linkID` plus columns for `categoryID` and `objectID`.

Given that setup, I would create three entities in CoreData: `Category`, `Object` and `Category_Object`, and give them attributes to match your Azure Mobile Services tables.  Then define relationships between them:

- Category has a to-many relationship to Category_Object, say `objects`, with a to-one inverse, `category`.
- Likewise Object has a to-many relationship to Category_Object, say `categories`, with a to-one inverse, `object`.

Sync the `Category` and `Object` tables with CoreData first, then sync the `Category_Object` table.  Use the `categoryID` and `objectID` columns from that table to fetch the correct `Category` and `Object`.  Then populate the relationships:

```
newCategory_Object.category = fetchedCategory
newCategory_Object.object = fetchedObject
newCategory_Object.linkID = linkIDfromTable
```

From then on in your app, you can use the relationships to determine which `Object`s belong to which `Category`s; no need to worry about joining tables.

Note that if the Category_Object table has no columns other than the `categoryID` and `objectID`, then theoretically you could dispense with the `Category_Object` entity in CoreData, and just have a many-many relationship directly from `Category` to `Object`.  But I think that will make syncing more complex.

Comment: This is what I thought. If I understand, after having syncing my tables. I should manually set the "Core data relationship". I was wondering if Azure would do something like thos automatically

Comment: @Hugo Sorry, I don't use Azure so cannot advise.

Comment: Yeah. My temporary solution right now is to sync my relation table and then assign the new relationships

Comment: Yes, that's what you have to do. The Mobile Services SDK won't reconnect relationships for you.

Comment: Do you know if the Mobile Services SDK will hew able to connect relationship in a next update. BTW, thanks to you two for the answers